# Item not deleting from SQlite Database

Tags: android, sqlite

In my app I have multiple markers that are added to the map and saved in SQLite,  but now i want to delete a specific marker when tapping on that marker and select "delete marker"  So what I have done is this:

In my `LocationsDB.class`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql = "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " +
                 FIELD_ROW_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement , " +
                 FIELD_LNG + " double , " +
                 FIELD_LAT + " double , " +
                 FIELD_ZOOM + " text , " +
                 FIELD_TITLE + " text , " +
                 FIELD_SNIPPET + " text , " +
                 " ) ";

    db.execSQL(sql);
}

public long insert(ContentValues contentValues){
    long rowID = mDB.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
    return rowID;
}

public int del(int id){
    int cnt = mDB.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, FIELD_ROW_ID+"="+id, null);
    return cnt;
}
```

Then in my `LocationsContentProvider.class`:

```
 public class LocationsContentProvider extends ContentProvider{

public static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "com.maps.locationsmaps.locations";
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + PROVIDER_NAME + "/locations" );
private static final int LOCATIONS = 1;
private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher ;

static {
    uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "locations", LOCATIONS);
}

LocationsDB mLocationsDB;

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    mLocationsDB = new LocationsDB(getContext());
    return true;
}

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    long rowID = mLocationsDB.insert(values);
    Uri _uri=null;
    if(rowID>0){
        _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, rowID);
    }else {
        try {
            throw new SQLException("Failed to insert : " + uri);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return _uri;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
    String[] selectionArgs) {
    return 0;
}
@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    int cnt = 1;
    cnt = mLocationsDB.del(cnt);
    return cnt;
}
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

    if(uriMatcher.match(uri)==LOCATIONS){
        return mLocationsDB.getAllLocations();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    return null;
}
}
```

And then finally in my `MainActivity.class`:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
    marker.remove();
    LocationDeleteTask deleteTask = new LocationDeleteTask();
    deleteTask.execute();
        }
    })

....

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
}
class LocationInsertTask extends AsyncTask<ContentValues, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(ContentValues... contentValues) {
        getContentResolver().insert(LocationsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, contentValues[0]);
        return null;
    }
}

private class LocationDeleteTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
   getContentResolver().delete(LocationsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null);
   return null;
```

This initially works when selecting "delete marker"  but when returning to the activity the marker then returns and doesn't get deleted?

Am not sure what i am doing wrong, so hoping someone could help me please?

Comment: where you are calling `delete` method ? and also show `LocationsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI` uri

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK:  I have updated my `LocationsContentProvider.class`  I call my delete method `public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
    marker.remove();
    LocationDeleteTask deleteTask = new LocationDeleteTask();
    deleteTask.execute();`

Comment: have you try call `mLocationsDB.del(cnt);`  directly in `doInBackground` in place of `getContentResolver().delete` ? for testing

Comment: and also call `getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);` after delete operation

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK: have tried that but no luck.

Comment: @Newbie in `LocationDeleteTask ` you are not passing any params, how do you know which row to delete?

Comment: @Yazan:  sorry, but I am not quite sure what you mean?

Comment: @Newbie when the user touch a `marker`, you remove that marker `marker.remove();` from map, then you execute instance of `LocationDeleteTask`, right? when you initiate and execute that class `LocationDeleteTask` you are not passing any ROW_ID, MARKER_ID or any other params that will be used in Delete, so you just remove the marker from the map and not from DB, once the activity reloaded the marker is still exist in DB and so it will be reloaded to the map view

Comment: @Newbie you are always deleting row with id = 1, from the hardcoded line `int cnt = 1;` in `LocationsContentProvider#delete()`

Comment: @Yazan:  Thanks, I understand that part now, but then how would I pass the params that will be used in delete?  Would I do it at: `protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {`?

Comment: @Newbie i will write you an answer if minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, when you query (fetch) the locations from DB and add them as markers to the map, you need to keep track of marker databse-ID, maybe `ArrayList` you are not including this part of code, but i assume you know what i mean,

when you add marker, it returns marker-id (id on the map) not the id of db-row so the arraylist or hashtable will be a mapper between marker id and row-id at db.

i will write some snippets, you can figure out where to insert and use

```
Hashtable <Integer, String> mapid_dbid = new Hashtable <Integer, String>()
private void populateMap(){
    while(some cursor loop){
        Marker marker = new Marker(... init from DB);
        int mapid = map.addMarker(marker);
        //mapid her is an ID generated for the marker once it's added to the map
        mapid_dbid.put(mapid, cursor.getString("row_id"));
    }
}
```

now we move to the onClick(), you need to use `onMarkerClick` from class [OnMarkerClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener.html)

add this listener to the `mapview` ( maybe at `onCreate()` ) of the activity.

```
@override
public boolean onMarkerClick (Marker marker){
    marker.remove();
    LocationDeleteTask deleteTask = new LocationDeleteTask();
    deleteTask.execute(marker.getId());
}
```

now we modify the DeleteTask: (change 1st Void to Integer) it's the in-params type.

```
private class LocationDeleteTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {//note Void changed to Integer too
        //paramsnow params might be 1 or more, so in this case we sent 1 param, so we read it as params[0]
        //and it's the markers Map-id, we need to get the db-id from the hashtable.
        String dbId = mapid_dbid.get(params[0]);

        getContentResolver().delete(LocationsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, new String[]{dbId});//pass dbid of the location to the delete, so it can be passed to db-delete
        return null;
    }
}//Task
```

now the Provider, we change delete() method:

```
@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    int cnt = 1;
    cnt = mLocationsDB.del(selectionArgs[0]);
    return cnt;
}
```

i don't have all of your code, so you have to try finding out what should you do
to make this fit in your code,

main idea, is to get the marker id (from map) and use it to get db-id of the location
then pass it to the deleteTask, that will pass it to the Provider,
and the provider will pass it to the sqlite helper.